# Excel formula where row number depends on the column number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The essence of the formula is that for a cell with column A8 in the table below, there must correspond a cell with row A8 in the table above (A<N> column - A<N> row, like that). An example of how it needs to be done is below:
[image]

My current formula:

```
=SUM(IF($B2:$M2>$B9:$M9; $B$18:$M$18; 0)) / SUM($B$18:$M$18)
```

An example of its application you can see in the screenshot below:
[image]

The current version does not support the desired behavior, so I have to copy the formula for each cell and manually move the range of cells up/down.

I tried to ask chatGPT, but all his suggestions don't work, and I really would like to automate this formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following in `B21` and drag right/down:

`=SUM(IF(INDEX($B$2:$M$16,XMATCH($A21,$A$2:$A$16),)>INDEX($B$2:$M$16,XMATCH(B$20,$A$2:$A$16),),$B$18:$M$18,0))/SUM($B$18:$M$18)`

It's the same formula you used, but the ranges are indexed using INDEX / XMATCH.

When using an older excel use:
`=SUM(IF(INDEX($B$2:$M$16,MATCH($A21,$A$2:$A$16,0),)>INDEX($B$2:$M$16,MATCH(B$20,$A$2:$A$16,0),),$B$18:$M$18,0))/SUM($B$18:$M$18)`